# Query mongodb using form-submitted data with both radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, express

I'm building a form using express which has multiple groups of radio buttons and checkboxes. When submitted, the form selections are used to query the "parts" collection in my database.

Form example:

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radioOption1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radioOption2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkOption1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkOption2">
```

If you select the first radio and first checkbox options and submit, the req.body looks like:

```
    {radio:'radioOption1', checkbox:'checkOption1'}
```

Which works fine when using this mongo query to find documents with a matching option_name:

```
    db.collection('parts').find({option_name:{$in:req.body}})
```

However, if you tick both checkboxes, req.body turns into:

```
    {radio:'radioOption1', checkbox:['checkOption1','checkOption2']}
```

While $in still finds a match for the radio button key/value, it doesn't work for the checkboxes, now that they are stored in an array. Is there a way to change my query, or my data, to solve this problem?

edit:
The Parts collection has documents that look something like:

```
    {
      "option_name" : "radioOption1",
      "price" : 100
    }
    {
      "option_name" : "radioOption2",
      "price" : 200
    }
    {
      "option_name" : "checkOption1",
      "price" : 300
    }
    {
      "option_name" : "checkOption2",
      "price" : 400
    }
```

edit2:
Danish's answer solves the riddle. In Express, before running the query, I do:

```
    var productOptions = []

    // iterate thru req.body
    for (var key in req.body) {
      // check if array
      if( Object.prototype.toString.call(req.body[key]) === '[object Array]' ) {
        // push each array value to productOptions
        for(var i = 0;i < req.body[key].length;i++) {
          productOptions.push(req.body[key][i])
        }
      } else {
        productOptions.push(req.body[key])
      }
    }
```

then changed the query to use the new productOptions array:

```
    db.collection('parts').find({option_name:{$in:productOptions}})
```

That works! Please let me know if my javascript could be cleaner.

Comment: Looked at this for a few minutes but trying to get my head around your schema. Would be good if you could edit with a few sample documents from the collection you are searching. Also $in expects an array of fields or documents which is not what you are passing in.

Comment: Edited to include some sample documents. I suppose my big question is whether I should be using $in, or if there is another way. $in "works" and finds a document for any property value in the req.body that is a string, but it doesn't parse the property values that are arrays.

Answer (score 1):

$in will work fine. just form a array of all your options in req.body like:

```
 ['radioOption1', 'checkOption1','checkOption2']
```

now use this,

```
 db.collection('parts').find({option_name:{$in:['radioOption1', 'checkOption1','checkOption2']}})
```

This will retrieve all documents where option_name is either radioOption1 or checkOption1 or checkOption2.

Comment: That does it, thank you! Edited the question to show how I made your solution work in Express.